# Генерация чисел c++

Tags: c++

Имеется следующий код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;


void main()
{
    int n, k;
    cout << "Enter the size of the first array: ";
    cin >> n;
    cout << "Enter the size of the second array: ";
    cin >> k;
    srand(time(0));
    int* arr_1 = new int[n];
    int* arr_2 = new int[k];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) // Заполнение первого массива
    {   
        arr_1[i] = rand() % 10;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << arr_1[i] + " ";
    }
    system("pause");
}
```

Однако при генерации чисел вместо чисел генерируются какие-то символы, по типу `"Ь2XЭ2░Ю2╘Ю2Я2HЯ2Э2░Ю2╘Ю2Я2HЯ2Э2░Ю2╘Ю2Я2HЯ2Э2░Ю2╘Ю2Я2HЯ2Ь2XЭ2░Ю2╘Ю2Я2HЯ2"`. В чём проблема?

Answer (score 5):

Вместо

```
cout << arr_1[i] + " ";
```

Напишите

```
cout << arr_1[i] << " ";
```